# How to Parse XML Where Child Nodes Have The Same Name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that I am parsing through and have come across a specific element that has it's own child nodes. The XML file is below:

```
<status.AppleSettings>
    <AppleInstance MaxCost="250" Status="77" NewMode="5" SharePrice="350"
                   FlagTF="False" TimeClock="0" TimeClockSec="14"
                   Options="7532890" ID="JK_7755" Owner="SLP90"
                   Server="PA.SL90.COL" Name="SLP90" GroupName="COL.PA"
                   Instance="AppleServiceInstance" NewFlag="True" FinalCount="0"/>
    <AppleInstance MaxCost="5" Status="0" NewMode="1" SharePrice="0"
                   FlagTF="False" TimeClock="300" TimeClockSec="1000"
                   Options="56794577431" Owner="A.CON" Instance="SL91"
                   NewFlag="True" FinalCount="1" List="1450, 1430"
                   Keyrepo="SYSTEMSERVER_7671902"/>
</status.AppleSettings>
```

As you can see, there's a parent node - AppleSettings and then two child nodes w/ the same name - AppleInstance. I created two separate classes for the child nodes since they have different attributes. I am able to access AppleSettings and when I do a quickwatch I can see the two child nodes inside, I just can't figure out how to access them. New to XML parsing and C# so everything is trial and error, learning a lot from stackoverflow.

Here is the code I have to access the AppleSettings parent node:

```
    private List<Data> GetAppleSettingsNode(List<XmlDocument> XMLdocument, List<Data> DataList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < XMLdocument.Count(); i++)
        {
              AppleSettings temp = new AppleSettings();

              var temp2 = XMLdocument[i].DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//AppleSettings");
              foreach (var node in temp2)
             {
                var temp3 = node.ToString();
             }

              XmlNode xmlNode1 = XMLdocument[i].SelectSingleNode("//AppleSettings");

              XmlSerializer serial1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppleSettings));

              temp = (AppleSettings)serial1.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode1));
         }
     }
```

Is it even necessry to access the AppleSettings node? Could I go directly to the two AppleInstance child nodes? If someone could help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What about generating classes using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe ?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API.

(1) The code below shows how to access any XML attribute by its name.

(2) `.FirstOrDefault()?.Value` technique will prevent exceptions generation when an attribute is missing.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\AppleSettings.xml";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    foreach (var el in doc.Descendants("AppleInstance"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MaxCost={0}", el.Attributes("MaxCost").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance={0}", el.Attributes("Instance").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("GroupName={0}", el.Attributes("GroupName").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }

    public class Root
    {
        [XmlArray("status.AppleSettings")]
        [XmlArrayItem("AppleInstance")]
        public List<ApppleInstance> AppleInstances { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ApppleInstance
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int MaxCost { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Status { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int NewMode { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int SharePrice { get; set; }

        private Boolean _FlagTF { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string FlagTF 
        { 
            get { return _FlagTF? "True" : "False";}
            set { _FlagTF = (value == "True") ? true : false;}
        }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int TimeClock { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int TimeClockSec { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public long Options { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Server { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        private Boolean _NewFlag { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string NewFlag
        {
            get { return _NewFlag ? "True" : "False"; }
            set { _NewFlag = (value == "True") ? true : false; }
        }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int FinalCount { get; set; }

        private int[] _List { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string List 
        {
            get { return string.Join(",",_List);}
            set { _List = value.Split(new char[] {','}).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray() ;}
        }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Keyrepo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The i of LargeXMLResponse[i] is loop count of the Large XML response if your response tag in wrapped up in between, and if you have a alternative way please go ahead with.

var ResponseToList = LargeXMLResponse[i].Descendants("Response").ToList();

```
if (ResponseToList.Count() > 0){

for (var pf = 0; pf < ResponseToList.Count(); pf++)
{
ResponseInfoList.Add(new ResponseToList{

id = ResponseToList[pf].Descendants("Block").Attributes("id").Count() > 0 ? 

ResponseToList[pf].Descendants("Block ").Attributes("id").First().Value : "",

});
}
}
```